# Assigning multiple strings to single variable

Tags: java, string, variables

So i'm working on a bowling calculator assignment that takes a series of inputs and calculates a score. The test input provided by my instructor has a number of test cases which denote how many strings will need to be computed to scores. The problem I am having is that I am not able to get all 3 strings (there are 3 test cases) into a single string, separated on different lines.

This is what the input is:

3
--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--

X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,XXX

X,13,X,81,5/,X,18,33,X,X36

I am trying to get it to be formatted as such:

--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--

X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,XXX

X,13,X,81,5/,X,18,33,X,X36

However, when I run my code I get this as the output:

--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--
X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,XXX
X,13,X,81,5/,X,18,33,X,X36

Here is what I've got so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bowling {
  public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inFile = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(inFile);

    int tc = scanFile.nextInt();
    String N = "";


    for (int i=0; i < tc; i++)
        N += scanFile.next();
    System.out.println(N);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Thank you everyone for the answers, I have learned quite a bit because of your responses. At the time of asking this question I was tied up on this problem and was not thinking straight. I looked over my code again and realized all i had to do was add this line before the strings were added to the variable:

```
N += "\n";
```

Again, thanks to all those who commented.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a [`StringBuilder`](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrE19gpi1tcAQYAduxXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEydHZvc2NsBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMyBHZ0aWQDQjI5NDRfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1549532073/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Flang%2FStringBuilder.html/RK=2/RS=va0U4W_xMruaKEVyewWWkDIT72k-) if you are going to be concating a lot of `String`'s. But on every iteration of the loop, you can append a newline character:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < tc; i++) {
    sb.append(scanFile.next());
    sb.append("\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `StringBuilder` is for efficiency.  Using `+=` like the OP uses is very inefficient.  Normally the rule is "no optimization until profiling" but sometimes you do optimize automatically, this is almost always one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to:

• Make a String[] array

• Use dividers, like \t

• Use other methods

Also, don't forget to say that you want us to tell you how to use newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to use StringJoiner in your case,I totally agree with @GBlodgett's answer. But this too can serve as an alternate.

From the javadoc,

> StringJoiner is used to construct a sequence of characters separated
>   by a delimiter

which exactly suits your case. Your loop reads as,

```
StringJoiner sj= new StringJoiner("\n"); // Here, "\n" is the delimiter between every join.

for (int i=0; i < tc; i++){
       sj.add(scanFile.next());
}
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Also, this avoids appending unnecessary newline after the last appended line.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a bug in your code that explains why the output is in one line.

The command System.out.println(N) should be inside the for loop.
The variable N is unnecessary - please omit it.

There is another problem of resource leakage in your code, because the Scanner was never closed. The scanner should be closed using the auto closeable mechanism (by using try with resource statement).

I propose the following code to solve the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inFile = new File("input.txt");
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile)){
        int tc = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i < tc; i++) {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
    }
}
```